# python scrapy - scraping from onclick popup dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape all the links to videos and English transcripts from [this site](http://saltanat.org/videos.php?topic=SheikhBahauddin) using scrapy and python

I got the spider to scrape all the video URL's from all pages (NB. i am useless at programming), but i cant figure out how to scrape the transcripts. The transcript dialog only pops up after clicking a button. The links to the transcripts are found on this new popup. All other tutorials I've read address POST requests, but it seems like this is an ajax GET request. (So I'm completely clueless what to do). I've also seen posts that mention payloads and form control, but i have no idea what they are for this site

**relevant HTML from page before button click:**

```html
    <span class="transcription make-cursor" onclick="showTranscriptionDialog('17394')"> 
<img class="video-doclet-icons" src="images/transcript4.png" 
title="Download Transcription, Tercüme'yi indir, تحميل النص" 
alt="Transcription" data-pin-nopin="true"></span>
```

**relevant HTML after click (of dialog popup):**

```html
    <span class="ui-corner-all" id="transcription-language-list17394" 
style="background-color: rgb(245, 243, 229); color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"> 
<a class="transcription-language-list" target="_blank" 
href="http://saltanat-transcriptions.s3.amazonaws.com/english/2017-08-08_en_NothingMeansEverything_SB.pdf" 
onmouseover="transcriptionLanguageMouseOver(17394)" 
onmouseout="transcriptionLanguageMouseOut(17394)" 
style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"> English </a></span>
```

**my current spider code (not working)**

```html
import scrapy

class SuhbaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "suhbas"
    start_urls = ["http://saltanat.org/videos.php?topic=SheikhBahauddin&gopage={numb}".format(numb=numb)
  for numb in range(1,23)]

    def parse(self, response):
   yield {
                'video': response.xpath('//span[@class='download make-cursor']/a/@href').extract(),
            }
  videoid = response.xpath("substring(//span[@class='media-info make-cursor']/@onclick, 22, 5)").extract()
        for p in videoid:
            url = "http://saltanat.org/ajax_transcription.php?vid=" + p
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_transcript)

    def parse_transcript(self, response):
            yield {
                'transcript': response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,'english')]/@href').extract(),
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 2 way to do it. You could execute javascript with a webdriver and simulate a click on the button. Or you could do the GET request yourself then parse the response. Open your browser's dev tools in the network tab and check what it is doing when you click on the button. Try to do the same request in your python code.

Comment: @rm4 Thanks for the reply, I'm not too keen on using a webdriver thing, I've attached my code for my spider above where i tried to do it based on your second option. Problem is I'm not getting any results when i run the spider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing around with the code i got a working solution, the problem was the "substring" command. It shouldn't have been put in the "response.xpath" line. I used an alternate syntax to do the same thing as shown below (viz. getting a substring)

**Not working part**

```html
videoid = response.xpath("substring(//span[@class='media-info make-cursor']/@onclick, 22, 5)").extract()
        for p in videoid:
            url = "http://saltanat.org/ajax_transcription.php?vid=" + p
```

**replaced with this working part**

```html
fullvideoid = response.xpath("//span[@class='media-info make-cursor']/@onclick").extract()
    
 for videoid in fullvideoid:
  url = ("http://saltanat.org/ajax_transcription.php?vid=" + videoid[21:-2])
```